# PHP display error

Tags: php, mysql

I've created the following code but for some reason it is echoing **Array** instead of the result:

```
<?php
    include("../config.php");
    include("functions.php");

    $count = "SELECT `monthly_slots` FROM users WHERE `username` = 'Bill'";
    $count = mysql_query($count);
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($count);
    echo "$data";
?>
```

Any ideas?

I have no idea why it is outputting Array because there should only be one result from that query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql_fetch_assoc() returns an array, you need to use `print_r($data)` instead, to dump out the array's contents.

Comment: also, you might want to echo "<pre>" before and "</pre>" after the print_r to nicely format it in the browser

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
print_r($data);
```

This will output the contents of the array.

The return type of `mysql_fetch_assoc` is array. So you should use `print_r` to see the result.

```
Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data
pointer ahead. mysql_fetch_assoc() is equivalent to calling mysql_fetch_array() with MYSQL_ASSOC 
for the optional second parameter. It only returns an associative array.
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [`array`](http://php.net/array) manual page explains, when you output an array variable in string context (as `echo` does here) it will become just `"Array"`.

To see the array contents use [`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r) or [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) instead:

```
print_r($data);
```

Or better yet just access the content you wanted:

```
print($data["monthly_slots"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is expected. You should try `print_r($data)`

Answer (score 0):

**Solutions**

- You could simply print out the whole contents of the array with

  `print_r($data)`

however I wouldn't usually recommend doing it like that considering you're only looking for a specific item soo..

- You could also try referencing the output as the first item (assuming there is only one result) with

  `echo "$data[0]";`.
- you can also simply reference the specific item in the array you are looking for with

  `echo $data['monthly_slots'].`

**References:**

- [php arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
- [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)
- [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

Answer (score 0):

use `print_r($data)` to print the `$data` array, or `$data['column_name']` for a perticular row. because `mysql_fetch_assoc()` aloways returns an array.